# Python: Loop Through All Column Headers In DataFrame and Create New Dictionary For Each Column Header With Key:Value Pairs Based on Two Columns

Tags: pandas, loops, dictionary, header

I currently have the sample dataset below

[image]

I want to do the following:

1. Create a variable for each column header (except house) that holds a data dictionary
2. The data dictionary from above holds the "House" number as the key and info from that column as the value

For example if I typed in `Bedrooms` in Python the resulting output would be:

```
{'House1': 0,
 'House2': 1,
 'House3': 4,
 'House4': 3}
```

Or if I typed in `condition`: result would be

```
{'House1': new,
 'House2': old,
 'House3': old,
 'House4': new}
```

I tried the code below:

```
for col in df.columns: 
    col = dict(zip(foods_vector, df[col]))
```

But the above code is wrong because it doesn't save each dictionary to its corresponding header column variable.

Answer (score 0):

This function would do:

```
def get_dict(df, col, indexed='House'):
    return df.set_index(indexed)[col].to_dict()

get_dict(df, 'condition')
# {'h1': 'new', 'h2': 'old', 'h3': 'old', 'h4': 'new'}
```

Comment: this is not quite what I'm looking for; I need to be able to execute ONLY the column header / variable name (i.e. run 'condition' within python and have it spit out the desired result).  The reason is I need to use the variable name itself for other things later in my code

Comment: dynamic variable names, while possible in Python, are strongly discouraged, since it can override system variables (think if I have a column named `list`). Also, what you are asking is a example of [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).